# Need help in GPS location on android

Tags: android, gps, location

I need a simple code snippet which can do the following. 
I need a function which can do the following.

1. check if GPS is enabled. If not enabled, then enable it.
2. check for the current location, i.e get longitude and latitude
3. Disable the GPS.

I don't need the continuous location update like LocationListener. Just once in 15 mins is ok.
can anybody provide me working code snippet for this?

Comment: AFAIK you can't enable the GPS programatically. you'd have to go with LocationManager/Listener and set the update interval to 15 minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For enabling GPS:

```
private void turnGPSOn(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }
```

For disabling GPS

```
 private void turnGPSOff(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }
```

To check GPS is on or not.

```
if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }
```

For getting current location.

```
public void getCurrentLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager;
        String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);
        Criteria crta = new Criteria();
        crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        crta.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        crta.setBearingRequired(false);
        crta.setCostAllowed(true);
        crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crta, true);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,
                new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                            Bundle extras) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            double lat = location.getLatitude();
                            double lng = location.getLongitude();
                            if (lat != 0.0 && lng != 0.0) {
                                System.out.println("WE GOT THE LOCATION");
                                System.out.println(lat);
                                System.out.println(lng);
                                getAddress();                           
                            }
                        }

                    }

                });
    }
```

Comment: hi Noby, Thanks very very much for providing the detail code. As I am very new to java, i like to know is it possible for me to create java class in android with extending it from any other parent class like activity,service or broadcast reciever? I want a simple java class which will contain all your above methods and I will call those from other activities or classes. I put the above code in a simple java class and imported the "import android.provider.Settings", but still it is showing error for "getContentResolver()". could you plz help in this?